# QTabBar custom css

Tags: css, qt, qtabbar

I'm trying to refine the Breeze Dark theme for konsole using custom CSS, but I cannot figure out the selector which gets picked when the konsole content changes and the tab get becomes **highlighted** (if you know what I mean; it merely means that the unselected tab text color gets changed when the content of the shell changes). Not hover though, as hovering works the over way.

Reading the official documentation doesn't clarify me (I suppose I'm using it wrong, but anyway). Does anyone know the name of the property/selector ?

Also, it would be nice if my custom  CSS would be *merged* with teh default one, overriding only the things that I change, and leaving others intact. I expected this to be the default behavior, but seems like I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some official examples for [customizing QTabWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar).
Namely, you would need `::tab` subcontrol and `:selected` pseudo state in your stylesheet. For example:

```
QTabBar::tab:selected {background: red;}
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't bothered reading examples, especially google first hit and ran here to ask [sarcasm]. It's not :selected either. *Selected* is merely a selected tab. And the highlighted tab is always unselected. And not, not every :!selected.